# Is it a good idea to store user location and home address in a database?

Tags: database, security, encryption

I'm making an android application that will require users to enter their home address. I need to store these addresses as I will use them to send users letters and packages.

My database is stored on a shared host.

All the info will - of course - be stored in encrypted form. I just wanted to know if it's a good idea to store this info in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

It doesn't really matter  'where' you store them but how well you protect the storage engine.Secure the database properly and you've got no problem

Comment: Thank you for answering :) . Always a pain finding secure ways to store data, and I currently can't afford to hire a professional.

Comment: @UndercoverCoder  ..there ain't no free lunch...no pain no gain...if you cant hire a professional,go through the PAIN or risk the consequencies

Comment: You're right. No pain no gain. I rather not face the consequences.